# Is this Update statement syntax valid or not

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm creating a table that takes its data from another table and shows it to the user according to the value he enters in an entry box. This update statement is a bit too long I'm sorry bear with me but I can't get any output about it.

I've already tried creating many update statements but the result was the first line that matches the condition only and I want all rows that match the conditions.

```
c.execute("""UPDATE Pdct_tbl SET Store_Code = (SELECT Store_Code FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?), Store = (SELECT Store FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Product_Date = (SELECT Product_Date FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Permission = (SELECT Permission FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Product_Code = (SELECT Product_Code FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Product_Name = (SELECT Product_Name FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Incoming = (SELECT Incoming FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Unit_Buying_Price = (SELECT Unit_Buying_Price FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Total_Buying_Price = (SELECT Total_Buying_Price FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Outgoing = (SELECT Outgoing FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Unit_Sell_Price = (SELECT Unit_Sell_Price FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Total_Sell_Price = (SELECT Total_Sell_Price FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Description = (SELECT Description FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?),
        Quantity_In_Seberbay = (SELECT SUM(StoringTF.Incoming) - SUM(StoringTF.Outgoing) FROM StoringTF WHERE StoringTF.Store_Code = 2 AND StoringTF.Product_Code = ?),
        Value_In_Seberbay = (SELECT SUM(StoringTF.Total_Buying_Price) - SUM(StoringTF.Total_Sell_Price) FROM StoringTF WHERE StoringTF.Store_Code = 2 AND StoringTF.Product_Code = ?),
        Quantity_In_Morashaha = (SELECT SUM(StoringTF.Incoming) - SUM(StoringTF.Outgoing) FROM StoringTF WHERE StoringTF.Store_Code = 1 AND StoringTF.Product_Code = ?),
        Value_In_Morashaha = (SELECT SUM(StoringTF.Total_Buying_Price) - SUM(StoringTF.Total_Sell_Price) FROM StoringTF WHERE StoringTF.Store_Code = 1 AND StoringTF.Product_Code = ?),
        Quantity_In_Nouran_Store = (SELECT SUM(StoringTF.Incoming) - SUM(StoringTF.Outgoing) FROM StoringTF WHERE Store_Code = 3 AND StoringTF.Product_Code = ?),
        Value_In_Nouran_Store = (SELECT SUM(StoringTF.Total_Buying_Price) - SUM(StoringTF.Total_Sell_Price) FROM StoringTF WHERE StoringTF.Store_Code = 3 AND StoringTF.Product_Code = ?)
        """,(Val))
```

I expect the output to be a table but git bash just gets stuck and doesn't show a thing. I'm sure the problem is in this because when I tried it with multiple update statements it worked but only showed first row as mentioned above.
Can you please help me with this and I'm so sorry for length of code but I had to show it all because the mistake could be anywhere in this statement or the whole statement altogether.
The question mark represents an empty slot for val variable at the end that comes from user input and I'm certain there's nothing wrong with that part.
Thanks for your patience and hope you can help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The last line needs to pass the parameter as many times as the placeholder appears:

```
""",[Val]*19)
```

Comment: even if that parameter represents a tuple? or will it be different ? Thanks a lot for your help and your patience

Comment: You didn't say that Val was a 19-tuple. I assumed it was a Product_Code.

Comment: It's a one element tuple and that element is indeed the product code entered from the entry box and it needs to be assigned to them all. Anyway python returned a table when I did what you said but the problem is. It still gave me the first row only. Is there a way to fix this or is it unsolvable. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I really need help in here. Can you please stay with me till we solve this because I can't solve it by my own. Thanks a lot for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

If `val` is already a singleton tuple, you’d write:

```
 val*19
```

If `val` is the value to be used, you could write:

```
(val,)*19
```

As for the number of rows returned, maybe you could provide further information, e.g.

1) what is the value of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StoringTF;
```

2) how are you determining how many items are in the result set?

---

p.s. It might be helpful, both to yourself and to others, if you could reproduce the problem with a very small table, and update the question so it's more in accordance with the http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve guidelines.

Comment: The value of SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StoringTF; is not static. It changes whenever the user adds data 
I cannot determine how many. I want that table to be equal to SELECT * FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = Val
But it returns 1 row with this update statement. That's my main problem here. If you solve it I'd be really honestly very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll find that `execute("""UPDATE ...""")` normally returns an empty table.  As the manual says, `Although the Cursor class of the sqlite3 module implements this attribute, the database engine’s own support for the determination of “rows affected”/”rows selected” is quirky.` So if you want the number of rows affected, you'll have to do a separate `SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE ...;` query.